# Upload Image from Android to asp.net

Tags: android, wcf, file-upload

I get the below error:

```
Cannot process the message because the content type
'multipart/form-data;
boundary=0JxmnFLOmjvutAKrtR1bmPCqpG8M6WbwE-aAvh8' was not the expected
type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
```

---

**Android Code:**

```
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.9.103/AndroidService/MediaUploadService.svc/uploadFile1");
        File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "01.jpg");
        MultipartEntity t = new MultipartEntity();
        t.addPart("t", new FileBody(photo));
        httppost.setEntity(t);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

**WCF Code:**

```
public class MediaUploadService : IMediaUploadService
{
    public void UploadFile(Stream fileContents)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
        int bytesRead, totalBytesRead = 0;
        do
        {
            bytesRead = fileContents.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
        } while (bytesRead > 0);
        File.WriteAllText(@"D:\\Vechile\log2.txt", totalBytesRead.ToString());
    }
}
```

Can some one help me to do this process ?

My problem :- 
Need to upload image files from Android to Server (via IIS -> .asp,.asmx,.svc etc)

Could any one suggest me on this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Something that you could do is to send 2 parameters to the url :

- fileName = the filename
- fileContent = content of file encoded in base64

In your asp file, just get the 2 parameters content, make a base 64 decode, and write it in a file named as the filename parameter ...